# Exist -webkit- in max-width?

Tags: css

i want to change the max-width to the div only in mobiles

```css
.test{
max-width: -webkit-100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">test</div>
```

If webkit doesn't work, how can I put a max width for mobile?

Thanks!!

Comment: How do you want to define a mobile. Do you mean mobile or do you mean maximum viewport width is less than something, say  600px? If the latter, use media query.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, simply by using `max-width` without any prefix, but using a media query

```css
.test {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .test {
    max-width: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test">test</div>
```

see also https://caniuse.com/?search=max-width